# How to set the color of plot legend independent of the plot itself

Tags: plotting

I have written the code below:

```
ListPlot[das1, PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle], 12}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red, 
 PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[Style[#, FontSize -> 20] & /@ {"6.7 ps"}, {Top, Right}]]
```

I want a black line to go through my red data points. Then, I want the plot legend to be red.

However, by using the above code I get a black plot legend.

[image]

How can I set the plot legend color independent of the plot itself?

How can I extend the solution to multiple graphs in one plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be by using `PointLegend`:

```
ListPlot[Range[10], PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledCircle]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{Red, Green}, 
    Style[#, FontSize -> 20] & /@ {"A", "B"}], {Top, Right}], 
 PlotStyle -> {Black}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]